# Show that $a\to f(a)$ from $A$ to $S$ is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I am reading "Continuity" in Metric Spaces

Suppose $S\subset \mathbb R$ is  a closed set. Suppose $A\subset \mathbb R$ has the property that for every $a\in A$ there is a unique nearest point $f(a)$ of $S$ to $a$. Show that $a\to f(a)$ from $A$ to $S$ is continuous.

Please give some hints on how to proceed. Please dont give complete solution

Comment: I don't think that's true, you can definitely always find a 1-1 function from a closed set to another set, that's not continuous.

Comment: Is there any relation between $a$ and $f(a)$? How is $f(a)$ defined?

Comment: Is this a problem from your book? Which book is it? This statement, exactly as you stated it, is false.

Comment: Question does n't make any sense(atleast to me)

Comment: To make what I said more precise, you can always find a function that's not continuous as long as the domain $A$ does not inherit the discrete topology.

Comment: Sorry @GregoryGrant;@Crostul I missed "nearest"

Answer (score -1):

Hint: If $f$ were not continuous, then there would exist a sequence $a_n \to a$ such that $|f(a_n) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. However, at the same time we have $$|f(a) - a| \leq |f(a_n) - a| \leq |f(a) - a_n| \leq |f(a) - a| + |a - a_n|,$$ so that $|f(a_n) - a| \to |f(a) - a|.$

To conclude the argument, take a convergent subsequence of $f(a_n)$ (*Question: why does a convergent subsequence exist?*).

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I will try to finish that and let you know

Comment: I have doubts about this (partial) answer. Why "$ |f(a_n) - a| \leq |f(a) - a_n|$"?