# Nearest point map in finite-dimensional subspace of normed space is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, approximation-theory

I am going through Carothers's *A Short Course on Approximation Theory* ([link](http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/%7Emk/approx1011/carothers.pdf)), and contemplating the following lemma.

> **Lemma 1.9.** Let $Y$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of a normed linear space $X$, and suppose that each $x \in X$ has a unique nearest point $y_x \in Y$ such that $\displaystyle ||x-y_x|| = \min_{y \in Y} ||x-y||$. Then the nearest point map $P: x \to Y; x \mapsto y_x$ is continuous.

> *Proof (sketch):* Suppose $x_n \to x$ in $X$.
>
> 1. Show $(P(x_n))$ is bounded, and hence has a convergent subsequence (say, to $P_0$).
> 2. By "passing to a subsequence", $P(x_n) \to P_0$.
> 3. Establish the inequality $||x-P_0|| \leq ||x-P(x)||$, and thus $P_0 = P(x)$ by the uniqueness of nearest points.

I have the following questions, corresponding to the steps numbered above:

1. Is this a straightforward application of Bolzano-Weierstrass?
2. Why does the convergence of a subsequence of $(P(x_n))$ imply the convergence of the whole sequence?

Comment: 1. Yes, except that you must first prove it is bounded.

Comment: 2. There seems to be an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278503) but I don't upvote it because I can't follow it (probable misprint(s)).

Comment: It may also be that what the author meant was $P(x_{s_n}) \to P_0$. Indeed, the following Exercise 1.10 establishes that whenever $x_n \to x$, the existence of some subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ converging to $f(x)$ implies $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @JakeLai Bolzano-Weierstrass forces the existence of a convergent subsequence, but we can say something stronger: if every convergent subsequence converges to the same point, then the entire sequence converges! You can prove it with the contrapositive: if a bounded sequence fails to converge to $L$, then there is a subsequence that stays some $\varepsilon$ away from $L$, and must have its own convergent (sub)subsequence. The proof is using this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, prove that $(P(x_n))$ is bounded:
   $$\begin{align}d(Y,x)&\le\|P(x_n)-x\|\\&\le\|P(x_n)-x_n\|+\|x_n-x\|\\&=d(Y,x_n)+\|x_n-x\|\\&\le d(Y,x)+2\|x_n-x\|.\end{align}$$
   Then, "straightforward application of Bolzano-Weierstrass" indeed.
2. It is false that "the convergence of a subsequence of $(P(x_n))$ implies the convergence of the whole sequence". Instead, two methods are possible:

- **the method of Theo's comment:** suppose we shall be able to prove (in 3.) that the limit of *every* convergent subsequence of $(P(x_n))$ is $P(x).$ [Using Bolzano-Weierstrass again, this will guarantee that $P(x_n)\to P(x),$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231888) thus ending the proof. So, replacing $(x_n)$ by some subsequence, still denoted by $(x_n)$ from now on, such that $P(x_n)\to P_0$, there remains to prove that $P_0=P(x).$
- **the method of Jake Lai's comment**, using Carother's exercise 1.10, valid for a map $f:X\to Y$ where $X,Y$ are *any metric spaces*, and better phrased: *If* [whenever $x_n\to x$, there *exists* a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ converging to $f(x)$], *then* $f$ is continuous at $x.$ So, there remains to show that $P_0=P(x),$ where $P_0$ is the limit of *the* converging subsequence of inherited from 1. and still denoted by $(P(x_n))$ from now on.

For the sake of completeness, here is a **solution of Carothers's auxiliary exercise 1.10**:
 Assume for contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at $x,$ i.e. there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ and such that $f(x_n)\not\to f(x).$ Then, for some $\epsilon>0,$ there exists, for all $N\in\Bbb N,$ some $n\ge N$ satisfying $d(f(x_n),f(x))\ge\epsilon.$ This allows to construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $d(f(x_{n_k}),f(x))\ge\epsilon$ for all $k.$ This sequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$ and there exists no subsequence of $(f(x_{n_k}))$ converging to $f(x),$ thereby ending the proof by contradiction.